# Are "Have you tried this..." considered to be real answers, or should they be flagged?

Tags: discussion, flags

I see many answers on the form

> Have you tried *X*?

where *X* is an untested potential solution to the problem.

Are these to be considered real answers, or should they be flagged as *"It should possibly be [...], a comment, [...]"*?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just treat the answer as if it were grammatically a statement, instead of a question, given that it's being proposed as a solution.  If you want, you can even edit the answer so that it is asserting its solution as an actual solution.

Given that it is in fact presenting a solution (the question is rhetorical, and not actually a request for clarification of the author) the post is most certainly not "Not an Answer" and should not be deleted or be converted to a comment.

Beyond that, simply judge the answer on its merits; if it's a good solution, despite the author's timid presentation of it, then it's still a good solution.  If it's a bad solution, then it's a bad solution, regardless of how timid or confident the author is when presenting it.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. However, I don't think it would be appreciated if I edited the post from *"Have you tried X?"* to *"The solution is X."* even though the answer is to be treated as if it was written in its second form.

Comment: @aioobe If you don't want to make such an edit, then you certainly aren't *forced* to.  It makes the presentation of the answer better for everyone else who's reading it later though, so it's certainly not an inappropriate edit.

Comment: "The solution _could_ be X"

Comment: @aioobe If the user doesn't like your edit then perhaps they *are* asking a question rather than answering. In which case if they state that or roll back, "I" would downvote and leave a comment stating "clarification should be in comments". I wouldn't do that without discussing first, or trying the edit approach.

Comment: My feeling is that in 9 cases out of 10, they *are* indeed asking a question, but hoping that their guess works out. If it doesn't work out and gets downvoted, I bet they wished they posted it as a comment. Personally I think the other way around is a better practice: Post the "Did you try X?" as a comment, and if they say "Yes, that's it!" I reformulate it as a proper answer.

Comment: +1 I often edit such questions in answers to form statements e.g. "Try X".

Comment: Interestingly, a week ago on SO I posted an answer which I am 99% confident, despite the question not providing enough details. I got a comment saying "This is a guess. It should be a comment." from a 10k+ user. That seems to contradict with what you said above. Now I'm more confused about the "norm" of SO. (Disclaimer: Not complaining, just want to know if I did the right thing or if I made a mistake.)

Comment: @ace They are most certainly not "Not An Answer" and don't merit deletion.  As to whether or not an answer that is a guess is a quality answer, given some amount of uncertainty in the question, is not a matter of policy; it is a matter of quality for each reader to judge when voting on an answer, and different people consider different levels of uncertainty in a question as appropriate/inappropriate.  Some people want there to be no uncertainty when a question is answered, some don't mind blind guesses, and everything in-between.